# GCP VPN phase 2 not established until traffic received

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vpn

We configured classic VPN on GCP to our on premise DC. It seems that tunnel on phase 2 is not established until some traffic sent from our DC. After this first ping or ssh everything runs fine. Problem is that tunnel is not being open when doing the same from GCP side. Btw we have cisco asa router on our side. Any suggestions what should we check?

Answer (score 0):

This is a guide to troubleshoot issues on Cloud VPN[1](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/support/troubleshooting).

I recommend you to search for error messages on the Cloud Router Logging, and send me what you found and I can further recommend you solutions for your issue.

Cheers!

---

Answer (score 0):

finally found the cause in [docs](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/interop-guides?hl=en). It is a limitation of our cisco asa device. We cannot configure more than one IP range there.